# CodeBlocks in LaTeX

Tags: code, sourcecode

I use the program 'CodeBlocks' to create some .c files. Is there a package that gives me the opportunity to have 
with a single command as output (on my PDF) the .c file with the same colours that CodeBlocks uses? (the .c file is in the same folder of my LaTeX document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `listings` package that does a lot on prettyprinting program code, but you will probably have to configure it to get the same colours as some other tool like CodeBlocks chooses.

Comment: Thank you! but I hope that there is some package dedicated to CodeBlocks.